# Set length of stroke-dasharray and dashoffset with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I have the following animation with CSS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="247pt" height="543pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 246.86 543.19">
   <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 539.1859)">

<style>
#a1123 {
stroke-dasharray: 100.5;
stroke-dashoffset: 100.5;
animation: dash2 2s linear infinite;}
@keyframes dash2 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}
#a1124 {
stroke-dasharray: 100.5;
stroke-dashoffset: 100.5;
animation: dash2 2s linear infinite;}
@keyframes dash2 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}
</style>   
   <g id="node4" class="node">
         <title>c</title>
         <ellipse fill="none" stroke="#000000" cx="211" cy="-315.8894" rx="27" ry="18" />
         <text text-anchor="middle" x="211" y="-311.6894" font-family="font-awesome" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">c</text>
      </g>
      <!-- 2&#45;&gt;c -->
      <g id="a1123" class="edge">
         <title>2-&gt;c</title>
         <path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M149.4218,-420.9789C160.4144,-409.9076 171.2176,-397.7063 180,-385.1859 188.9863,-372.3746 196.3054,-356.5405 201.5708,-343.2434" />
         <polygon fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" points="204.9306,-344.2533 205.1904,-333.6617 198.3823,-341.7795 204.9306,-344.2533" />
      </g>

      <!-- c&#45;&gt;e -->
      <g id="a1124" class="edge">
         <title>c-&gt;e</title>
         <path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M208.109,-297.8625C205.1217,-279.2357 200.2512,-248.8658 195.5911,-219.8076" />
         <polygon fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" points="198.9943,-218.9251 193.9549,-209.6055 192.0827,-220.0336 198.9943,-218.9251" />
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

But the problem is that the attributes `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` are set statically here. But I want to compute the length of every edge and set `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` via javascript with the computed path length. How can I do that? I tried many things but it doesn't work.

**UPDATE**
With the code @Alexandr_T has given, I have update my code and I am able to compute the length of the path. And I am getting the value, but setting the value via javascript does not create the animation like I have it in the first part of the code with CSS. There must be something I am doing. Here the code via javascript (I kept both codes in the question, so you can see the first code which I want to achieve, but via javascript and the second code which is the current status via javascript):

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        path.style.strokeDasharray = len;
        path.style.strokeDashoffset = len;


        alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
  <style>
#a1123 {
animation: dash2 2s linear infinite;}
@keyframes dash2 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}
#a1124 {
stroke-dasharray: 100.5;
stroke-dashoffset: 100.5;
animation: dash2 2s linear infinite;}
@keyframes dash2 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}
</style>
<body>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="247pt" height="543pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 246.86 543.19">
   <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 539.1859)">

        <g id="node4" class="node">
             <title>c</title>
             <ellipse fill="none" stroke="#000000" cx="211" cy="-315.8894" rx="27" ry="18" />
             <text text-anchor="middle" x="211" y="-311.6894" font-family="font-awesome" font-size="14.00" fill="#000000">c</text>
        </g>
          <!-- 2&#45;&gt;c -->
        <g id="a1123" class="edge">
             <title>2-&gt;c</title>
             <path fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M149.4218,-420.9789C160.4144,-409.9076 171.2176,-397.7063 180,-385.1859 188.9863,-372.3746 196.3054,-356.5405 201.5708,-343.2434" />
             <polygon fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" points="204.9306,-344.2533 205.1904,-333.6617 198.3823,-341.7795 204.9306,-344.2533" />
        </g>

          <!-- c&#45;&gt;e -->
        <g id="a1124" class="edge">
             <title>c-&gt;e</title>
             <path id="check" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M208.109,-297.8625C205.1217,-279.2357 200.2512,-248.8658 195.5911,-219.8076" />
             <polygon fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" points="198.9943,-218.9251 193.9549,-209.6055 192.0827,-220.0336 198.9943,-218.9251" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

</body>
```

Comment: [Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) might be what you're after.

Comment: This is SVG, not HTML.

Comment: @RobertLongson I have update the question

Comment: @Code Pope I apologize, but you misunderstood my explanations in the first answer. The script I gave is needed to manually calculate the length of the line. The script should be in a separate HTML file. You manually each time substitute the patch values from your application into this file. Press the "Total" button the received digit is already used in the css rules of the -dashoffset line

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the length of the path using the command  JavaScript `getTotalLength()`

```js
 `<script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>`
```

The resulting number will need to be used in `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset`

At the maximum value of `stroke-dashoffset` the line will be hidden,
 with `stroke-dashoffset = "0"` the line will be drawn completely.

For the convenience of calculating the `stroke-dashoffset 'for each patch, I use this technique:

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
  <input  type="button" value="Total"  onclick="TotalLength()"/>
 <div>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" > 
 
         <path id="check" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 539.1859)" fill= "none" stroke ="red" stroke-width ="1" 
         
  d="M208.109,-297.8625C205.1217,-279.2357 200.2512,-248.8658 195.5911,-219.8076" />
</svg> 
</div>
   <script>
         function TotalLength(){
          var path = document.querySelector('#check');
        var len = Math.round(path.getTotalLength() );
        alert("Path length - " + len);
        };
  </script>
```

You can copy this file to your local computer and use it every time you need to calculate the length of the patch.

To do this, you need to take from your application the parameter "d" of your patch and insert it instead of the existing one in the file.

After changing the value of "d", press the <kbd>Total</kbd>

**Update**

`The getTotalLength ()` method only supports the `patch`
To calculate the length of `polygon` in your application, make the `polygon` conversion into a `patch`

```
<polygon fill="#ff0000" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" points="204.9306,-344.2533 205.1904,-333.6617 198.3823,-341.7795 204.9306,-344.2533" /> 

 <path d="M204.9306,-344.2533 205.1904,-333.6617 198.3823,-341.7795 204.9306,-344.2533"/>
```

Comment: be aware of `getTotalLength()` not working on some browsers (ex:safari).

Comment: @Timothy Lee Unfortunately I can not check in the safari, but in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE11 running

Comment: Safari and old version firefox not support :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength

Comment: @Timothy Lee I'm not arguing :) Suggest your solution

Comment: I know you're not :) just want to post the link.

Comment: @TimothyLee old versions of Firefox do support getTotalLength, you're misreading the documentation. The method was simply moved to a superclass which should not affect either this or pretty much any existing use cases.

Comment: @Alexandr_T I don't know why but running your code, I cannot see any line on the web page. I just see the button

Comment: @CodePope You have an "translate" in the source code, so you did not see the line. Added to your example is your offset - transform = "scale (1 1) rotate (0) translate (4 539.1859)" and the red line became visible But in general it's not necessary to see the line, you only need the digit of the length of the line that appears after you click on the "Total"

Comment: Or just use pythagoras theorem on the polygon points to calculate its length yourself.

Answer (score 1):

*New answer for questions and answers in the comments*

I do not know what kind of animation you want to get in the end.

But if you are satisfied with the successive animation of drawing arrows, triangles, then I can suggest the following option.

I converted in your code   `polygon` --> `path`
I learned using the method `getTotalLength ()`  length of all patches:

`#firstLine - 90.4px 
 #firstTriangle - 29px
 #secondLine -  79px
 #secondTriangle - 28px`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Generated by graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304) -->
<!-- Title: G Pages: 1 -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="247pt" height="543pt" viewBox="0.00 100 246.86 543.19">
   <g id="graph0" class="graph" transform="scale(1 1) rotate(0) translate(4 539.1859)">

<style>

#firstLine {
stroke-dasharray: 90.4;
stroke-dashoffset: 90.4;
animation: dash1 2s linear forwards;}
@keyframes dash1 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}} 

#firstTriangle {
stroke-dasharray: 29;
stroke-dashoffset: 29;
animation: dash2 1s linear 2s forwards;}
@keyframes dash2 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}} 

#secondLine {
stroke-dasharray: 79;
stroke-dashoffset: 79;
animation: dash3 2s linear 3s forwards;}
@keyframes dash3 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}    

#secondTriangle {
stroke-dasharray: 28;
stroke-dashoffset: 28;
animation: dash3 1s linear 5s forwards;}
@keyframes dash3 {to {stroke-dashoffset: 0;}}  



</style>   
   <g id="node4" class="node">
         <title>c</title>
         <ellipse fill="none" stroke="#000000" cx="211" cy="-315.8894" rx="27" ry="18" />
         <text text-anchor="middle" x="211" y="-311.6894" font-family="serif" font-size="18" fill="#000000">c</text>
      </g>
      <!-- 2&#45;&gt;c -->
      <g id="a1123" class="edge">
         <title>2-&gt;c</title>
         <path id="firstLine"  fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M149.4218,-420.9789C160.4144,-409.9076 171.2176,-397.7063 180,-385.1859 188.9863,-372.3746 196.3054,-356.5405 201.5708,-343.2434" />
         <path id="firstTriangle"  fill="none" transform="translate(-2 -3)" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M204.9306,-344.2533 205.1904,-333.6617 198.3823,-341.7795 205.9306,-343.2533" />
      </g>

      <!-- c&#45;&gt;e -->
      <g id="a1124" class="edge">
         <title>c-&gt;e</title>
         <path id="secondLine"  fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M208.109,-297.8625C205.1217,-279.2357 200.2512,-248.8658 195.5911,-219.8076" />
         <path id="secondTriangle" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-width="3" d="M198.9943,-218.9251 193.9549,-209.6055 192.0827,-220.0336 198.9943,-218.9251" />
      </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```